# MPI MPI_REDUCE MPI MINLOC

Tags: c, data-structures, mpi

I am using MPI_REDUCE to find the minimum value calculated on different processors in C.

If two ranks calculate the same global minimum value, does MPI_MINLOC then determine the minimum rank value out of the two and use it as the location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information [here](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node79.html), your belief is correct. Specifically quoting from that page:

> Note that if MPI_MAXLOC is applied to reduce a sequence of pairs , then the value returned is (u , r), where and r is the index of the first global maximum in the sequence. Thus, if each process supplies a value and its rank within the group, then a reduce operation with op = MPI_MAXLOC will return the maximum value and the rank of the first process with that value. Similarly, MPI_MINLOC can be used to return a minimum and its index. More generally, MPI_MINLOC computes a lexicographic minimum, where elements are ordered according to the first component of each pair, and ties are resolved according to the second component.